# How to lookup word in a string and assign values

Tags: excel

I have a problem with excel. I have 2 columns, in column A I have a keyword which is occuring in string that is in column B. All I try to do, is to assign the keyword in column C to the strings in which they occur.

Example:

[image]

I tried to use vlookup but I'm still getting errors.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `C1` cell, enter next formula in formula bar, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag it down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$11,B1)),-1,ROW($A$1:$A$11)))-ROW($A$1)+1)
```

---

**Here is some explanations:**

**1)** `FIND($A$1:$A$11,B1)` - here we tries to check whether the values from `$A$1:$A$11` are substrings of value in `B1` cell. If yes, we'd get location of a substring in `B1`, if no - we'd get `#VALUE`. We'd get something like this here: `{#VALUE,#VALUE,13,#VALUE,#VALUE}`

**2)** `IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$11,B1)),-1,ROW($A$1:$A$11))`. Here we change locations of found substring to it's row number, and change `#VALUE` to `-1`. Here we got stn like this `{-1,-1,3,-1}`

**3)** `MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$11,B1)),-1,ROW($A$1:$A$11)))` returns `3` from `{-1,-1,3,-1}` - row number of substring

**4)** next, using `INDEX()` we got corresponding value, using its row number

Comment: Excellent solution. It would be helpful if you can explain it a bit as this is a complex formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Though in excel 2013 the formula should be separated with semicolons and look like this: =INDEX($A$1:$A$11;MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$11;B1));-1;ROW($A$1:$A$11)))-ROW($A$1)+1)

Comment: You are welcome:) it depends on your local settings)

Comment: One more thing. Part of my keywords uses hyphen and the string in which I'm looking are using underscores. Is there a way to match the results, taking into consideration the hyphens? E.g. I'm looking for a "key-word" and the string is "www.xyz.com/xzy/999/key_word_xyz"

Comment: You can change `FIND($A$1:$A$11;B1)` to `FIND(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$11;"-";"_");B1)`